# Can IUserMapper be used to Change User Details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nancy

In [Nancy FX](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki) how can I use the `IUserMapper` (if at all) to change a logged in users account details (name, email, password)?

```
// registering is straight forward
Post["/register", true] = async(parameters, ct) =>
{
    var user = this.BindAndValidate<UserRegistration>();
    var response = await mapper.RegisterUser(user); // user is registered
    ...
}

// but how can I change a registered user's details?
Post["/profile", true] = async(parameters, ct) =>
{
    this.RequiresAuthenticationAndLogOut();
    var user = this.BindAndValidate<UserRegistration>();

    var response = await mapper.?????(user);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use the `IUserMapper` at all, this really only exists for authentication purposes and nothing more.

When a user is authenticated then you get access to the `UserName` property. If you setup your mapper to assign the user's Id to the UserName then you can load your user, modify, and commit.

i.e:

```
Post["/profile", true] = async(parameters, ct) =>
{
    this.RequiresAuthenticationAndLogOut();
    var user = this.BindAndValidate<UserRegistration>();

    var existingUser = await db.LoadAsync(int.Parse(CurrentUser.UserName));

    existingUser.Name = user.Name;
    ...

    return ...;
}
```

Also, you should never persist an object that's been bound from a client. The user may submit additional information you don't want them to.

Also I don't know where you got your `IUserMapper` from because in Nancy there is no Register.